# PostgreSQL how to pass more than 100 arguments to a function

Tags: postgresql

I am working on writing a function in PostgreSQL, which need to have more than 100 arguments. When I tried to run statement, server complains that function can not have more than 100 arguments.
So I want to know is there any way to override that limit and how? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a red flag that there is something wrong with your function design.

Comment: I agree that I need to revisit my function design, BUT question remain the same that is PostgreSQL itself imposes limit of 100 parameter max? If yes then why 100? If not then Is there any way I can change it to some large number like 120? Is this technically possible?

Comment: The answer is [yes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-preset.html). Think about it for a second. If you do this, you are ignoring the problem, and asking for help with a solution. This can never be good.

Comment: What makes 120 large and 100 not large? I can't recall ever passing more than maybe half a dozen arguments to a function.

Comment: @Burhan Thanks for providing link, that answers my question.

Comment: so 100 parameters to function are allowed and not considered as large, but 101 is large. I don't understand this.  Also PostgreSQL should allow to change this at run time, at this moment one has to recompile server again to get this in picture.

Comment: @user2541859: I totally agree. 99 params is supported and 100 is a "red flag" ... ???

Comment: @BurhanKhalid how do you figure? Is `json_build_object` poorly designed, or should you never have more than 50 properties on a JSON object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use arrays as parameters

Comment: This is good as you just passing one parameter as array and that array can have more than 100 values in it. There is no limit.

Comment: Can you write any example?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You can **pass one `record`** with many columns instead. Or multiple such records.

Tip: you can also use record of **type of existing table** from DB or **create new table type** for this to have all benefits of strict-typed coding.